# Is the reading 軍神 【ぐんしん】, 軍神 【いくさがみ】, or 軍神 【ぐんじん】?

Tags: readings, multiple-readings

Here https://www.fnn.jp/articles/286014

was the sentence

亡【な】くなられた[9人]【きゅうにん】は、戦争【せんそう】の士気【しき】を高【たか】めるうえで「軍神」になったんです

*The nine men who died became "war heroes" in raising the morale of the war effort.*

I found this dictionary entry

軍神 【ぐんしん; いくさがみ; ぐんじん[ok]】 (n) (1) god of war; (n) (2) war hero

How are the different readings of 軍神 used?

Comment: [西住小次郎](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%A5%BF%E4%BD%8F%E5%B0%8F%E6%AC%A1%E9%83%8E) is known as the first "[official 軍神](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%BB%8D%E7%A5%9E#%E8%BF%91%E4%BB%A3%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%81%AE%E8%BB%8D%E7%A5%9E) declared by Imperial Japan Army". And [this page](https://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/1718962/13) in a book published in 1939 says he was ぐんしん.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern Japanese, it's read ぐんしん most of the time.

Between ぐんしん and ぐんじん, ぐんじん may be an old variation or even a more standard way to read it a while ago, but it's mostly replaced by ぐんしん now. It doesn't help that 軍人 is also read ぐんじん.

It looks like the term means "legendary war hero [who was human before dying]" and "deity of war [who is always immortal]". I feel like in the latter sense it's more likely to be いくさがみ.

http://doi.org/10.15024/00002106 gives a summary on the old usage of "ikusagami". (I don't know if the author intentionally avoided using "gunshin" and "gunjin", though.)

The 9 individuals mentioned were named 九軍神 and there might be a customary way to read it as a proper noun. I don't know if it's きゅうぐんしん or きゅうぐんじん, but I'm pretty sure it's not きゅういくさがみ.

Comment: +1. I'd like to add that the borderline between "軍神 as a war hero" and "軍神 as a war deity" has been somewhat blurry in the Japanese culture. There are shrines throughout Japan that honor historical heroes as *kami* (eg [東照宮](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T%C5%8Dsh%C5%8D-g%C5%AB)).